the essential nature of ≪ the » family bond

Can the phrase "be family" be used to refer to the essential nature of
the family bond, rather than just being a family member? [my sentence]

Is the correct?
I am not talking about a specific family bond, but rather the concept of a "family bond".
It might be better to use "family bonds" instead of "the family bond".
Thank you.

Plural is better, there being different bonds within the family. Unless you are referring to a bond that is the same for all members, the parent-child bond being no different than the sibling bond or the bond between spouses.  And there are "kin" bonds that extend beyond   "nuclear" family.  So we may not know what you are speaking about when you use the word "family" or the word "bond".

Thank you, @TimR. I was thinking about the relationships of people who have no blood relation, but feel a sense of closeness as if they were family.

We do say that people who are not related by blood can "feel a kinship" for each other or "feel like family" to each other,  but the phrase has no exact meaning.

I thought the phrase "feel like family" was impossible because there's no determiner before "family". I guess it's a commonly used expression. I'll look up how it's used. Many thanks, @TimR.

The word that is being determined is "bond". There are different types of "bond" but here the speaker is specifically talking about the type of bond that is found within families.  As which type of bond is specified by the adjunct "family" it is correct to use "the family bond".
As is often the case, when using "the" to indicate a determined type, it is also possible to use a plural.  Compare "The lion is a big cat from Africa and Asia" with "Lions are big cats from Africa and Asia".
